# add labels dynamically in Charts.js

Tags: php, json, ajax, chart.js, responsive

I have done my graphs and its working perfectly but I'm having some issues when I'm trying to show the labels dynamically. I think it has something to do with the part of 'labels' but I'm not really sure.

This is the part of the code which I want to modify the array of 'labels', showing the information I have on my database not inputting the values by myself

```
success:function(response) {
        var Datos = {
            labels: ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
            datasets: [
                {
                    fillColor: 'rgba(153,102,255,0.6)',
                    strokeColor: 'rgba(57,194,112,0.7)',
                    highlightFill: 'rgba(153,102,255,0.6)',
                    highlightStroke: 'rgba(66,196,157,0.7)',
                    data: response
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

I have checked through my browser and indeed its sending the data but I don't know how to configure the labels dynamically.

How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you receive in the `response` variable?
If you have an array of labels, you can do something like this:

```
success:function(response){

    // Let's assume you got a JSON formatted response
    var labelsArray = JSON.parse(response);

                              var Datos = {
                                    labels : labelsArray,
                                    datasets : [
                                        {
                                            fillColor : 'rgba(153,102,255,0.6)', 
                                            strokeColor : 'rgba(57,194,112,0.7)', 
                                            highlightFill : 'rgba(153,102,255,0.6)', 
                                            highlightStroke : 'rgba(66,196,157,0.7)',
                                            data : response
                                        }
```

Of course your "labelsArray" must be a properly formatted array to work with Chart.js. In case you receive an object with indexes, you need to use other array functions in order to create your labels array.

Comment: I receive all the data as just one array